# Fetching BLOB data and inserting into a Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a BLOB content stored in a table (x_files) with MIME_TYPE = 'text/plain' , I want to parse this BLOB data and want to insert the data into a table (TEMP_UPLOAD_DATA) having a VARCHAR2 column.

Can you please help me with a sample code .. If you have? I Have written a code as mentioned below - if I do a DBMS_OUTPUT things are working fine, but when I am trying to insert the data into the table things are not working fine

Is it that I need to convert the BLOB to CLOB first and then parse and insert the data into the Table? Request your inputs

Tables in my database:

```
Table_name: X_files
ID  BLOB_CONTENT    MIME_TYPE   FILE_NAME   LAST_UPDATED    CHARECTER_SET
7   BLOB    text/plain  testing_blob.txt    01/28/2013  - 

Table name: TEMP_UPLOAD_DATA 
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
UPLOAD_COLUMN   VARCHAR2(1000)  Yes - 

-
```

Code which I have written :- 
This is working fine when I do a DBMS_OUTPUT , but not working fine when i am trying to insert the data into the table.

```
DECLARE
l_num NUMBER(8);
i NUMBER(4);
lob_loc  BLOB;
update_details VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
SELECT BLOB_CONTENT INTO lob_loc FROM x_files WHERE  id = 7; 
update_details := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(lob_loc, 10000, 1));
l_num := (LENGTH(update_details)-LENGTH(REPLACE(update_details,'@@')))/LENGTH('@@');
for i in 1..l_num 
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STRING IS---' || SUBSTR(update_details,instr(update_details,'@@',1,i),(instr(update_details,'##',1,i)-instr(update_details,'@@',1,i)+1)));
--INSERT INTO TEMP_UPLOAD_DATA VALUES(SUBSTR(update_details,instr(update_details,'@@',1,i),(instr(update_details,'##',1,i)-instr(update_details,'@@',1,i)+1)));
END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag this with JDBC when you are doing it in PL/SQL?

Comment: "but when I am trying to insert the data into the table things are not working fine" . any chance of knowing what you mean? i.e what error message. As when I tested it with some short sample data, it worked ok. Perhaps your string exceeds 1000 characters after you've applied the substring?

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how simple it can be to insert substrings of blob data into a varchar2 column. The original question has a myriad of incomplete setup scripting the code is blending in more commands than the question demands.

```
create table blob_table ( id number primary key, blob_content blob );
create table char_table ( id number, char_content varchar2(10) );

insert into blob_table 
     values (1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'));

insert into char_table (id, char_content) 
     select bt.id, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(bt.blob_content, 10, 1)) 
       from blob_table bt 
      where bt.id = 1;

select * from char_table;

        ID CHAR_CONTENT
---------- ------------
         1 ABCDEFGHIJ
```